# Multi parameter ranking using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, ranking

How can I leverage Firebase to develop a mixer algorithm similar to [Twitter](https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/the-algorithm/tree/main/home-mixer), which retrieves and ranks discussions from Firestore based on `weight` and `created_at` parameters?

I have a discussion collection with the following structure:

```js
interface Discussion {
    weight: number;
    created_at: ServerTimeStamp;
}
```

#### Challenge:

In Firestore, ordering data by a single field poses a limitation. For example, if we order discussions solely by `weight`, new posts will never have the opportunity to rise up in the ranking.

If I attempt to order discussions separately by `weight` and `created_at`, how can I handle `deduplication` effectively?

It's important to consider that the discussion documents can vary from `0 to 1 million`. Therefore, I prefer a solution that avoids loading all the documents on the client side. Additionally, any changes made must be reactive and utilize the `onSnapshot` method for real-time updates.

#### Example Scenario:

```js
interface Discussion {
    weight: number;
    created_at: ServerTimeStamp;
}

async function queryDiscussionFromFireStore () { 
   const col_ref = collection("discussion")
   // query top discussions
   const topPost_unSub = onSnapShot(query(col_ref, orderby("weight"), 
   (snapShot) => {
       setState(snapShort.doc.map (d => d.data() as Array<Discussion>)    
   })
   
   // query recent discussions
   const recentPost_unSub = onSnapShot(query(col_ref, orderby("created_at"), 
   (snapShot) => {
       setState(snapShort.doc.map (d => d.data() as Array<Discussion>)    
   })

   return () => {
     recentPost_unSub()
     topPost_unSub()
   };
}
```

`queryDiscussionFromFireStore` is working fine but i'm not able to figure out how to handle duplicate data.

let suppose we have following data:

```js
[
    {
        weight: 5,
        created_at: today_date
    },
    {
        weight: 3,
        created_at: today_date
    },
]
```

In this case both `snapShot` will response with same data.

#### Explanation

In the provided code example, the `queryDiscussionFromFirestore` function retrieves discussions from Firestore by ordering them based on two criteria: weight and created_at. The function uses the `onSnapshot` method to listen for real-time updates on the queried discussions.

However, there is a concern regarding duplicate data. In the given scenario, if multiple discussions have the same `created_at` timestamp, both the "top discussions" query (ordered by weight) and the "recent discussions" query (ordered by creation time) may return the same data.

For instance, considering the following example data:

```js
[
    {
        weight: 5,
        created_at: today_date
    },
    {
        weight: 3,
        created_at: today_date
    },
]
```

In this case, both `onSnapshot` callbacks for the "top discussions" and "recent discussions" queries will receive the same data, which results in duplicate entries being processed.

Comment: I'm not really clear what is the problem you're trying to solve here, but I don't think Firestore can do the query you want.  If you have some sort of custom sorting logic that's not just a straight sort on fields, that's going to have to be in your app, and you're going to have to load all the documents in order to apply that algorithm.

Comment: @DougStevenson if i explain in simple words i wanna to display list of discussion on my front page of the application. The list of discussion will be the mixture of `recent` and `top post`. where `recent` comming from order by `created_at` and `top post` from `weight`.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "order by created_at and top post from weight".  If would help if you showed actual data and code you're working with.  But if you can't take the sort order offered by Firestore, then you're going to have to perform multiple queries and assemble the results yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson let me show the code

Comment: There is no way to order/filter top results on multiple field in a single query. Each query can only have range filters on a single field. So you will have to perform multiple queries, and deduplicate the results in your application code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "deduplicate the results in your application code." that's good but still i'm reading extra docs from the firestore.

Comment: There is no way to prevent the extra reads. Well... there is a theoretical option if you find a way to merge the `created_at` and `weight` into a single value/property that you can filter on to meet your requirements, but the only real example of something like that that I know of are [geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) (which combine the lat/lon values of a point into a single string value that you can filter on to find documents in a region), and I personally don't see an equivalent here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you so much for help i'll look at how i can merge parameters into single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Firestore documentation on its [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So each query can only have range filters on a single field, and there is no way to order/filter top results on multiple fields in a single query. You will have to perform multiple queries and deduplicate the results in your application code.

That also means that there is no way to prevent the extra reads. Theoretically, you could find a way to merge the `created_at` and `weight` into a single value/property that you can filter on to meet your requirements, but the only real example of something like that that I know of are [geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) (which combine the lat/lon values of a point into a single string value that you can filter on to find documents in a region), and I personally don't see an equivalent here.